# Setting up rails dev env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, developer-tools

When I'm starting a rails app I usually go through the same process of getting my dev env set up. Adding `pry-byebug` or various `guard-*` gems, and initializing a `Guardfile`.

Is there a better way to automate this process?

Some ideas I thought of:

- Creating rake tasks that will add entries to `Gemfile`, run `bundle install`, and `bundle exec guard init livereload`, etc...
- Create a separate command line app that generates the right files and runs the right shell commands.

Is there another simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the templates method described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html). You create a file called `template.rb` that contains your desired gems, and commands. Then you create a new rails app with

```
rails new blog -m ~/template.rb
```

A sample `template.rb` is

```
generate(:scaffold, "person name:string")
route "root to: 'people#index'"
rails_command("db:migrate")

after_bundle do
  git :init
  git add: "."
  git commit: %Q{ -m 'Initial commit' }
end
```

Another way which I find much easier is just to maintain a github repository which contains everything you want in a bare bones Rails app. Then just `git pull` that into a folder when you want to create a new app. The only thing you'd have to overwrite would be the app's name in `application.rb`

Here is [github repo](https://github.com/mattbrictson/rails-template) that is a combination of both of sort, it's geared towards programming on Mac but easily changed.

Comment: Is it possible to add `rails` switches in the template, for example `--skip-spring`? I know you can add these to your `~/.railsrc` file, but curious if it's possible in the templates?

Comment: I haven't tried that actually, so I don't want to comment on it. I would imagine it would work though.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html#ask-question You can "ask" a question in the template and maybe just remove all spring related stuff if the answer is yes?

Answer (score 1):

See [Iceman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194312/2909897) for more info.

Using rails [application templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) is a great option.

For example if you want to get up and running with `guard-livereload` and `pry-byebug` and quickly scaffold a `Post` resource, then the following application template (it's just a ruby file) saved in `~/sandboxy.rb` would work:

```
gem_group :development do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
end


run 'bundle exec guard init livereload'

after_bundle do
  git :init
  git add: "."
  git commit: %Q{ -m 'Initial commit' }
end

generate(:scaffold, "post title body:text")
route "root to: 'posts#index'"
rails_command("db:migrate")

git add: '.'
git commit: %Q{ -m 'Scaffold a post' }
```

Then you can generate a new app with the following command:

```
rails new some_app -m ~/sandbox.rb
```