# How to generate a custom Rails application programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-generation

I want to create a custom Rails 5.x application programmatically in Ruby. Given a specification for the application, I want to generate a Rails application folder with that application in it. I can think of a few ways of doing this, but am not sure which is the idiomatic Rails way to do it.

Ideally, I would like the approach described in (5) below. 1-4 are workarounds I tried, but I would prefer a programmatic approach if available.

The example here is of the well known blog app:

1. Using system commands:

   ```
   `# my_app_maker.rb`
   `rails new blog`
   `cd blog`
   `rails generate resource Post title:string body:text`
   `rails db:migrate`
   `# <use a previously created template to modify the controller, layouts and views based on the app specification>`
   ```
2. Alternatively, I could do something similar but use scaffolding and then modify the templates as needed.
3. Use generators or engines. I do not know how exactly to do this.
4. Have a Rails application precreated and templatized and then use that to generate the Rails application.
5. Ideally, I would like an API to do this completely programmatically. Something like:

   ```
   app = Rails::App.new('blog', 'path/to/save/app')
   post = app.resources.add('Post')
   post.controllers.add_actions(['index', 'new']
   # ...
   ```

What is the most idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Read through the help available in the edit box when editing your text. It explains how to format your text like you wanted.

Comment: You can use Ruby to generate the shell commands, but you'd be better off doing it directly in a shell script; That's what they're for, to drive other apps. Then have Ruby call that script. This would be less system intensive and probably faster as you wouldn't be starting and stopping sub-shells repeatedly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up rails dev env](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194276/setting-up-rails-dev-env)

Comment: @theTinMan is there an API (such as the one described in #5 above)? My specifications can grow arbitrarily complex, and I would like to update the app programmatically, rather than using system commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, **rails application templates** are quite indicated for this particular job.
I think this is exactly what you need: a special API, wrapping common system commands, to create programatically new rails apps.

## Rails Application Templates

They are generators that generate a whole rails application.

You just have to put the commands in a ruby file, and then you create the app using:

```bash
$ rails new blog -m ~/template.rb
```

Here is an example from the guide:

```ruby
# template.rb
generate(:scaffold, "person name:string")
route "root to: 'people#index'"
rails_command("db:migrate")

after_bundle do
  git :init
  git add: "."
  git commit: %Q{ -m 'Initial commit' }
end
```

### Resources

The [Creating and Customizing Rails Generators & Templates guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) comes with a lot of explanation on how generators in general work, and the [Rails Application Templates guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) details the API that can be used for application templates.

Another good resource, is to look at the implementation of the [suspenders](https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders) gem, by Thoughtbot. It is a rails template that Thoughbot uses to bootstrap new projects.

I have myself created a rails generator to bootstrap new apps, with the gems that I need in all the projects and the common configuration. It saves me a huge amount of time when creating a new project.